# Migrating from .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently in the process of trying to migrate a project from .NET 3.5 to 4.5.1 using Visual Studio 2013. Every piece of documentation I've been able to find says that when you open a project with an outdated framework a wizard will pop up offering to migrate your project, however I have been unable to get that wizard. The obvious thing would be to manually change the target framework, however we have quite a large multi-solution project so this would not be ideal. Is there a way to explicitly invoke this tool?

edit for more info:

This is the wizard I was referring to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx

It does not just switch the target framework, it also updates references in the Web.config as well. Like I said, this is a very large project and I have no interest in doing this manually. I end up getting a lot (A LOT) of missing references when I try to do this manually.

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh266747%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) is [Round Trip](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx) compatible with 2012 and 2010 so there is no tool to run (if you are running a `.csproj` file).

The act of changing the framework version from 3.5 to 4.5.1 *is* the conversion process.

Comment: Yups. And optionally changing the required references of non-Framework assemblies, the redownloading of NuGet packages and the act of actually upgrading to new technology (MVC2 to MVC 5 for example).

Comment: Does it not normally update the Web.config file as well?

Comment: @Honanin Some things may need to be manually updated (like Jesse mentioned) I don't know if Web.config is one of them. Even if you could run the wizard (like coming from a 2008 project) I don't think the wizard will make those kinds of changes Jesse talked about.

Comment: Its worth adding to this that, while there are ways of shortcutting this framework change (such as a text replace in the csproj), its worth biting the bullet and doing properly, as the act of making the change will update other settings and designers related to the project at the same time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - It is.  Changing the target framework will update (at least) supportedRuntime, httpRuntime and compilation attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the wizard you're referring is the Project Upgrade Wizard and it's involved in upgrading the solution/projects (nothing to do with the target framework version).

To target a new framework, simply select a new framework version from the property pages.